# React Use-Hook-Form setFocus not Setting Focus between Bootstrap Accordions

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-hook-form

We have a 3 section form & we are requiring the user to fill out this form in a particular order pictured below (1. From Bin, 2. Item, 3. To Bin). Upon entering the required info in a section, the next section should automatically appear with focus on the first input. These 3 sections are simply part of 1 react-hook-form.

[image]

We are noticing, however, that react-hook-form's `setFocus` function does not set focus on the first input when we change sections and we can not seem to determine why this is or how to make it do so. I've seen a couple setTimeout hacks, but this does not seem like the correct approach.

Here is a simple [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-matan-geedx6?file=/src/App.js) we put together that replicates the issue.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using TypeScript, React and MaterialUI's accordion.  Opening an accordion element shifts the focus to its input element.

@Igor Gonak is correct; the root cause is that the `focus()` method does nothing on a DOM element that is not displayed.  You must delay calling `focus()` until after the accordion component has rendered.  You can do that with `setTimout()` (easier, see input one below) or by using a state flag that triggers a post-render effect (input two).

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Accordion, AccordionDetails, AccordionSummary } from "@mui/material";
import { ExpandMore } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { SyntheticEvent, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const ref1 = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const ref2 = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (focus) {
      setFocus(false);
      ref2.current?.focus();
    }
  }, [focus]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Accordion
        onChange={(_: SyntheticEvent, expanded: boolean) => {
          if (expanded) {
            setTimeout(() => ref1.current?.focus(), 100);
          }
        }}
      >
        <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMore />}>One</AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <input ref={ref1} placeholder="Input one" />
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion
        onChange={(_: SyntheticEvent, expanded: boolean) => {
          if (expanded) {
            setFocus(true);
          }
        }}
      >
        <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMore />}>Two</AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <input ref={ref2} placeholder="Input two" />
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <input placeholder="Input three" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi Steve, welcome to Stack Overflow! This particular question is asking about the react-hook-form library & bootstrap. Please read questions carefully before providing answers. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer, but be sure to fully understand the question before answering on Stack Overflow in the future. Again, appreciate you taking the time to share, but just fare warning, you will very likely get downvoted for answers like this in the future! Hope you have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the accordions component itself have not finish rendering and hence setFocus was called before accordion can fully render. Adding a timeout might help.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAccordionOpen) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setFocus("imageUrl");
      }, 50);
    }
}, [isAccordionOpen]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only point you to the right direction - this issue is because the accordion items are hidden. If I expand them all by setting activeKey and then navigate through the inputs, it works. Accordion.Body has display=none when collapsed and you can't focus hidden elements.

I thought it would fix it, when I set focus in useEffect, after activeIndex has changed, but this didn't fix the problem:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (activeSection === 1) {
      setFocus("itemID");
    }
    if (activeSection === 2) {
      setFocus("binTo");
    }
  }, [activeSection, setFocus]);
```

There are also no re-renders, which could lead to loosing focus.